# Pandas str.extract/ re.search using another series or column as a pattern

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':{0:'aa',1:'dd',2:'cc'},
                   'b':{0:'aa(bb)daa',1:'eedd(ed)',2:'affaa(f)'}})

    a   b
0   aa  aa(bb)daa
1   dd  eedd(ed)
2   cc  affaa(f)
```

I want to extract the characters inside the parenthesis as long as the pattern before the parenthesis is the value in df['a'].

I have tried using:

```
def searcher(x):
    pat_result = re.search(x[0] + '\((.*?)\)', x[1])
    if pat_result:
        return pat_result.group(1)

df[['a','b']].apply(lambda x :searcher(x), axis=1)

0      bb
1      ed
2    None
dtype: object

%%timeit
df[['a','b']].apply(lambda x :searcher(x), axis=1)
1.33 ms ± 3.49 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

I'm just wondering if there is a faster way (but still in pandas) or use str.extract directly?

Is there way to make this work?

```
df['b'].str.extract(df['a'] + '\((.*?)\)', expand=False)
```

Comment: Maybe using for loop is slightly faster

Comment: I believe `str.extract` can only be used on a series. In your case, you're operating on a dataframe.

Comment: @Wen I'm hoping to do it using pandas

Comment: @WStokvis I added to the question. `df['b'].str.extract('aa' + '\((.*?)\)', expand=False)` this will work

Comment: @fcsr You've hard coded in the value that would be in `df['a']`. In this case, it's `aa`. That doesn't provide you the answer you want since that value changes depending on the row.

Comment: @WStokvis yes I mean that pattern would work but I want to pass in a Series or Column, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses a loop. I ran the solution a few times and have gotten different times varying from faster to slower than the original solution.

```
%%timeit
for i, j  in df.iterrows():
    pat_search = re.search(j['a']  + '\((.*?)\)', j['b'])
    if pat_search:
        j['c'] = pat_search.group(1)
#First Iteration
264 µs ± 12.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
#Second Iteration
1.62 ms ± 78.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

For comparison to your original solution,

```
%%timeit
df[['a','b']].apply(lambda x :searcher(x), axis=1)

1.34 ms ± 101 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I was hoping to use something within pandas itself. I could also do `[re.search(df['a'][x] + '\((.*?)\)',df['b'][x]).group(1) if re.search(df['a'][x] + '\((.*?)\)',df['b'][x]) else None for x in df.index] 96 µs ± 189 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)`